# Access ViewChild element within Input in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ViewChild to isolate an HTML element in an Angular 2 component. I am trying to access it from within an Input. I am blanking on the proper syntax to target the element. Here is the code:

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('slideBg') el:ElementRef;

    @Input() public options: MnFullpageOptions = new MnFullpageOptions({
        navigation: true,
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
            // does not work:
            this.el.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    …

}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using arrow function? And are you sure that `afterLoad` event will be executed after `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: afterload is being executed after ngAfterViewInit. I have not tried using the arrow function, I am not sure how it would be used here.

Comment: `afterLoad: (anchorLink, index) => {`

Comment: That works! Thanks Yurzui!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the function **setAttribute()** of **nativeElement** :

```
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
```